# PHP, Top search keywords ranking system

Tags: php, html

It will be annoying to run a query to get top 10 search keywords list to my db server.

So, I am thinking to build a code that generate the top list as a HTML file.

The server automatically generate the HTML file every 10 minutes.

Therefore, server wouldn't bother to run queries from all visitors.

Can you give me an idea how to start to build this code?

Comment: How much information you have on your table ? top 10 rank is not that hard query to make cache system for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First question is how often do you think you will have db query-s for top 10 search keywords? You can always create view of top 10 keywords or optimize separate table. I believe this is more architecture problem than implementation problem.

If non of the above is acceptable you can create some structure in separate file (you prefer HTML but i would rather go with XML, but that is my point of view). I would not go so far to use CronJob for this, because you can do it easy and fast with PHP + SQL and also, if you do not have dedicated hosting you will most likely have problems with your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a table of TOP 10, which has also timestamp, easiest way to do it to put it on each column. Then if that date is too old, you update that top 10 table.

In the otherhand, how many keywords do you have, if it's too hard to make query on each time? Maybe you need to rethink the DB structure?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a CronJob. A CronJob is a process that runs on the server at a set interval. You could set up a CronJob to run every 10 minutes. You would specify a PHP script as the target for this and in this script you can run the query and write a html page to disk.

You would need to contact your hosting provider to set this up for you. Just tell them what script to run and at what interval. Maybe they have tools for this in a back-end where you can set this up yourself.